# Laravel 5.6 Method [...] does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My Route:

[image]

My Model:

[image]

MyController:

[image]

End error:

[image]

I don't know this file don't working with Laravel 5.6. My friend is trying it with Laravel 4.2 but is working.
Are there any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: You should really start with a new Laravel tutorial. Laravel already has built-in `all` functions for models, and you don't want to do raw DB queries if you can avoid it.

Comment: Route::get('whatever', 'App\Http\WhateverController@whateverMethod')->name('route-name-optional');  And do make use of camelcase. whateverMethod has to be in your controller

Answer (score 0):

You have to start your classnames with a capital in Laravel 5 and up :)

And there is no method 'getall' in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Either use `all()` or `get()` but not `getall()` because that is not an eloquent method